# How do I update a counter of an associated object before it is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an attribute on my `Node` object called `cached_comment_count` where I need it to be updated whenever a new comment is created.

This is part of my `create` action in my `CommentsController`:

```
@node = Node.find(params[:node_id])
@comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
@comment.node = @node
@node.cached_comment_count = @node.comments.count
```

However, this doesn't work because when I do `@node.comments.count` that just returns the current comments on the `@node` object before this new `@comment` is saved.

What does work is if I do:

```
@node.cached_comment_count += 1
```

The obvious issue with this is that it is simply just an increment of 1 - and doesn't feel complete. The best, most complete, way is to get the `comments.count` after this save has taken place.

But I don't want to end up in an infinite loop.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consider [`counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache) rails functionality. You can check what is it by old, but still good [Ryan Bates railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

Comment: This is a best suggestion because it is increment in one SQL-query without any `after_*` callbacks.

Comment: I forgot that `counter_cache` was built specifically for this purpose. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

you may use [*counter_cache*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache)

**With this declaration, Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and then return that value in response to the size method**

```
 in comment.rb
      ##should look something like this
      ##add this column in node table....comments_count
       belongs_to :node, counter_cache: true
```

**by using @node.comments.size**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add after create hook inside your `Comment` model.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :increment_comment_cache

  private

  def increment_comment_cache
    self.node.update cached_comment_count: self.node.comments.count
  end
end
```

Then remove your logic from controller, remove lines

```
@comment.node = @node
@node.cached_comment_count = @node.comments.count
```

This way, you get very DRY way of updating cache count, from any place you create comment it will automaticaly update count for you